# How do I customise the payment page and/or return URL in the new Paypal business account?

Tags: paypal

My client's Paypal account is using the new interface. I've been right the way through it and I still can't find out where to customise the payment page, return URL, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: Downvotes are not much use if they're not explained ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: Note S.O. is the official Paypal support forum. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173138/is-stack-overflow-the-official-paypal-support-site

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible

What you want is hidden behind the person icon, but here are the steps you need to take.

1. Login to your account.
2. Press the My Paypal button on the top right
3. Click the person icon top right.
4. Click **"Welcome [your name]"**
5. Click My selling tools Click website preferences/custom payment
   pages

Comment: Actually this IS the actual answer to the problem ... sorry, perhaps it's not phrased correctly, feel free to edit.

Comment: Downvotes are not much use if they're not explained ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes